# middle-aged and middle-age difference in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

The headline is:

'The middle-aged sadness behind the cancel culture panic'

why midle-aged instead of mifle-age? when to use one or the other?

Comment: _Middle age_ is a period in a person's life. _Middle-aged_ is an adjective for a person in that age group. Presumably the headline means that the sadness is felt by middle-aged people.

Comment: As it happens, both the "standard adjectival" form ***middle-aged*** and the "noun adjunct" form ***middle-age*** work "okay" for the exact context. But note that this *doesn't* apply to the ***old age*** version (where only the noun adjunct version works when referring to, say, *His **old-age fussiness** irritates me*, but even that doesn't work too well). Check Google NGrams for a comparison of ***middle-aged spread, middle-age spread, middle aged spread, middle age spread*** - the first two (hyphenated) versions, which are equally common, are effectively indistinguishable in normal speech.